# Conditional Formatting (IF not empty)

Tags: excel, excel-2003, conditional-formatting

How do I conditionally format a cell so if not blank it is grey?

I tried to do 'not equal', but it didn't work.

I am using Windows Office 2003 with Windows XP at work. I don't see the same feature as below:

[image]

What I have tried so far:

[image]

Edit: Figured what was wrong. In my production (actual work Excel), they were filled with white color. It wasn't my Excel file, so I was not aware of this before.

Comment: What specifically did you try to do in Excel 2003? Can you include the example formula you use in the rule?

Comment: @DavidZemens I am working on a excel sheet where I need to keep track of multiple items, and when it is not blank I need to high light them.

Comment: Can you include an example of the formatting formula that you used? You indicated that you tried some formula, `I tried to do not equal, but it didn't work` -- can you show us what you tried?

Comment: @DavidZemens Yes, I have attached what I have tried so far (seperately). Thanks!

Comment: Looks like you have it all figured out now. Good job!

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can use Conditional formatting with the option "Formula Is". One possible formula is

```
=NOT(ISBLANK($B1))
```

[image]

Another possible formula is

```
=$B1<>""
```

[image]

Comment: Figured out the problem, in my production list, I have fill with color white orginally. `=NOT(ISBLANK(A1))` works. Thank you Teylyn.

Comment: I can confirm that this solution works in a formatted table.
Formula Is =NOT(ISBLANK($B1))
Then, make sure that the region your setting to conditional formatting is correct. Not sure exactly why this works but it does work correctly.
I wanted a similar solution but I had a week # in my Column-A, then blank cells until the next week but I wanted that week row highlighted.
This did the trick!

Comment: What if what needed is that only if the cell is not empty apply the conditional formatting.

Comment: I like `=$B1<>""` better as the formula is shorter and easier for others to understand.  This worked for me in Excel 2013.

Answer (score 23):

Does this work for you:

[image]

You find this dialog on the `Home` ribbon, under the `Styles` group, the `Conditional Formatting` menu, `New rule...`.

Comment: You will need to chnage the value in the  "Format only cells with:" dtopdown to "No Blanks".

Comment: @Declan_K - thanks you are right. I'm sure OP can figure it out, but I will update later (when I have a computer).

Comment: @Floris - Sorry for the delay response, I posted the question before I left my office. My office is still using Window XP with office 2003. I don't think I see the same box like yours.

Comment: Ouch... Microsoft change things a lot between versions. I may have an old laptop with XP somewhere. If I can get it to come back to life I may take another look. Otherwise - maybe someone else in the community has an answer for you in the meantime. I have updated the tag...

Comment: Glad someone else could help!

Answer (score 2):

In Excel 2003 you should be able to create a formatting rule like:

`=A1<>""` and then drag/copy this to other cells as needed.

If that doesn't work, try `=Len(A1)>0`.

If there may be spaces in the cell which you will consider blank, then do:

`=Len(Trim(A1))>0`

Let me know if you can't get any of these to work. I have an old machine running XP and Office 2003, I can fire it up to troubleshoot if needed.

Comment: Using `=$A1<>""` worked for me in Excel 2013.  I like this better than `=NOT(ISBLANK($A1))`.  It's a smaller formula and easier for others to understand.

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me:

=NOT(ISBLANK(A1))

I wanted a box around NOT Blank cells in an entire worksheet. 
Use the $A1 if you want the WHOLE ROW formatted based on the A1, B1, etc result.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This method works for Excel 2016, and calculates on cell value, so can be used on formula arrays (i.e. it will ignore blank cells that contain a formula).

- Highlight the range.
- Home > Conditional Formatting > New Rule > Use a Formula.
- Enter "=LEN(#)>0" (where '#' is the upper-left-most cell in your range).
- Alter the formatting to suit your preference.

Note: Len(#)>0 be altered to only select cell values above a certain length.

Note 2: '#' must not be an absolute reference (i.e. shouldn't contain '$').

Answer (score 0):

An equivalent result, "other things being equal", would be to format all cells grey and then use Go To Special to select the blank cells prior to removing their grey highlighting.